# How to filter Gmail headers and stop "via" into labels

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, x-forwarded-for

I have tried several ways to filter a type of email into a label but the filter doesn't work.

I used Google to find a script to move these kind of emails into SPAM, but these emails are not SPAM for me.  Instead, I just want to modify the script to move these emails to a certain label.

This is the script that I found:

```
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 5);

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) 
{
    var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) 
    {
        var message=messages[j];
        var body=message.getRawContent();

        if(body.indexOf("X-Forwarded-For: email@example1.com email@example2.com")>-1)
        {
            GmailApp.moveThreadToSpam(threads[i]);
        }

        Utilities.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

`X-Forwarded-For: email@example1.com email@example2.com` is the email address that I find in the "Show Original" option from the drop down menu.

Can you please help me modify the script to move these specific types of emails into labels and not spam?

Comment: ok, you found a script on the web but now you need to read the docs and attempt your modifications and show us whats not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

The script is moving messages to the spam folder because of this line: `GmailApp.moveThreadToSpam(threads[i]);`

If you want to apply a label to the messages instead of marking them as spam, you can use `threads[i].addLabel(label)`.  And to archive the messages so they move out of the inbox, you can use `threads[i].moveToArchive()`.

Here's an updated example for you:

```
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 5);

var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("LABEL NAME GOES HERE");

if (label == null) 
{
    var label = GmailApp.createLabel(label);
}

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) 
{
    var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) 
    {
        var message=messages[j];
        var body=message.getRawContent();

        if(body.indexOf("X-Forwarded-For: email@example1.com email@example2.com")>-1)
        {
            threads[i].moveToArchive();                
            threads[i].addLabel(label);
        }

        Utilities.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

That modified version allows you to specify the name of the label at the top.  If the label doesn't already exist, it will create it.  And then rather than moving the message to spam, it will archive it and apply your selected label to it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect! It works, thank you Calcolat! If I can bother you for one more thing, is it possible to add "Skip the Inbox (Archive it)" function so the email will go directly to the label and does not stack my inbox?

Comment: Glad it works.  Yes you can do that as well.  I've just updated my answer above with some changes that will both apply the label and archive the email for you.  Also just a quick tip, but if you have any comments or further questions, it's best to click the "add a comment" link under my answer and reply that way.  If you post comments or questions as an answer like this, they might get deleted if a moderator sees them.

Answer (score 0):

Great script - thank you. I modified id slightly to use the X_Binding ID because I found marketing messages (in this example the Royal Albert Hall) have an xbinding ID where as order confirmation mails do not! I set it up with a daily timer to clean up the junk!

```
function FilterVia() {
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 5);
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("CIRCULARS");
if (label == null) 
{
    var label = GmailApp.createLabel(label);
}
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) 
{
    var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) 
{
    var message=messages[j];
    var body=message.getRawContent();

    if(body.indexOf("X-Binding-ID: RoyalAlbertHallMarketing")>-1)
     {
        threads[i].moveToArchive();                
        threads[i].addLabel(label);
     }

         Utilities.sleep(1000);
     }
    }
}
```